# Check if an email address exists (not just regex-valid)

Tags: email, system-administration

Any ideas about how these guys http://www.tutorialspoint.com/verify_email_address.htm do it, given that most mail servers on the planet do not reply on VRFY? Do check with a valid and invalid email address - it even knows google's "catch-all" addresses

Comment: It seems to make it up! I tried three emails of mine, one gmail, one live, one work account. None were valid

Comment: I used 2 addresses one valid one not and it did found both but I think I know what they do. They try to send the email using rcpt to:<email@to.test> Google replies with: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6596 b8si18919954wjx.62 - gsmtp

Comment: [This site](http://email-checker.net/check) outlines the technique that they use.

Comment: Yes, that's what the RCPT I tried does. Simulates sending an email

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was pretty simple. They simulate sending an email and most of the mail servers (including Google) disclose the validity of the email address after the RCPT